# exception error in pcap.net

Tags: runtime-error, ipv4, pcap.net

i am using pcap.net to change packets and reconstruct an output pcap file. but in this part i have error.
could anyone say, how could i solve it?

```
if (packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Protocol == IpV4Protocol.Tcp)
                                {
                                    PayloadLayer Payload = null;
                                    if ((packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.Payload != null) && (packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.Payload.Length >= 0))
                                    {
                                        Payload = (PayloadLayer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.Payload.ExtractLayer(); //extract the data                                 
                                        tmpPacket = PacketBuilder.Build(packetTimestamp, ethernet, ipV4Layer, tcpLayer, Payload);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        tmpPacket = PacketBuilder.Build(packetTimestamp, ethernet, ipV4Layer, tcpLayer);
                                    }
                                }
```

this is my error :
Object reference not set to an instance of an object .(for ipv4Layer)

and the detail of the error:
Length = 'ipV4Layer.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Comment: Where do you initialize ipV4Layer?

Comment: at first time that i read input pcap file.

Comment: Please put the initialization code as well. It is probably just null at this point.